# Nginx match location for root path and all other paths separately

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I am running Play framework server behind nginx server. At the root path, I am serving static website and all other paths should be redirected to the Play server. I have the following `default.conf` file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` (The system is RHEL 6.7)

```
# to match the root path only to serve static website
location = / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        # try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /index.html;
}

# to match the cms login page
location /cms/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
}

# to match all the requests from the cms
location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
}
```

However, this configuration doesn't match the root path request. It gives 404 error. However, if I remove the third location rule, then it serves the static page at the root path.

Also, I noticed that first time I tried this, it worked. But now, it's not working any more. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The result you are getting is most likely due to the 2nd and 3rd location blocks not having "index" directives set. Except for well understood specific reasons, such as overriding the default index file type(s), the "index" should always be set at least within the server context or, preferably, within the http context. Similarly, the "root" directive should be set in the server context.

With your config, when a request hits the 3rd location block, there is no information your what to do with it. Actually, the 2nd block should not be needed from what you have described.

Also, as you are proxying to what appears to be another webserver, you need to ensure that this has the equivalent of "index" and "root" set.

Not sure exactly how the backend you are using works with respect to these. If not configurable there, then you must ensure that that every request hitting it has the URI spelt out fully.

To start with, depending on how exactly things are set up on your server, I will move the "index" and "root" directives up to the "server" level